# Angular 6 HttpErrorResponse 500 Internal Server on large recordset

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I am working on Angular 6/MVC/C# application. I have Kendo grid where user can copy/paste records from Excel and Save button, which calls ValidateNSave service. This service makes Post request to server side code. It is working perfectly as expected as long as number of records are say around 100ish. But for larger number of records it starts throwing error in console as shown below and does not hit server-side code. User may require to copy/paste as many as 1000 records.

```
zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:52609/BASE/MyProj//MyProjApi/ValidateReportData 500 (Internal Server Error)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:3243
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1245
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3276
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:1569
(anonymous) @ http.js:1629
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:161
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:6
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:127
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:124
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:107
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:176
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:161
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:17
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../src/app/components/forms/report-group-start-date.component.ts.ReportDataStartDateComponent.validateChanges @ report-group-start-date.component.ts:666
eval @ ReportDataStartDateComponent.ngfactory.js:39
handleEvent @ core.js:10251
handleEvent @ core.js:10796
dispatchEvent @ core.js:7710
(anonymous) @ core.js:8154
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:988
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3811
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
Show 16 more frames
validateNSaveService.service.ts:1370 Http failure response for http://localhost:52609/BASE/MyProj//MyProjApi/ValidateReportData: 500 Internal Server Error handleError in service ValidateNSave
core.js:1673 ERROR Http failure response for http://localhost:52609/BASE/MyProj//MyProjApi/ValidateReportData: 500 Internal Server Error
```

ValidateNSave service:

```
public validateReportData(indata: any): Observable<any[]> {
        var url = this.ValidateReportDataUrl;

        return this.http.post(url, indata)
            .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res))
            .pipe(
                tap(data => {
                    this.data = data.map(item => {
                        if (item.StartDate != null && item.StartDate != "")
                               item.StartDate = new Date(item.StartDate).toLocaleString("en", this.options).replace(/[^ -~]/g, '');
                        if (item.StopDate != null && item.StopDate != "")
                            item.StopDate = new Date(item.StopDate).toLocaleDateString("en", this.options).replace(/[^ -~]/g, '');

                    })
                }))
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

private handleError(error: any) {

        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error in Validate and Save';
          console.log(errMsg, 'handleError in service ValidateNSave');


        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Also, project is using
"rxjs": "6.2.0",
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2", (package.json)
I cannot figure out what is causing the error and what should be the resolution. Please guide!

Comment: I believe you will not be able to resolve this unless you'll have a look at the server's log. There might be something like db timeout or other process that depends on the amount of records to post. I don't see any way that you can have an internal server error without hitting the server.

Comment: How is it possible to "not hit server-side code" and nevertheless get Internal Server Error (or any HTTP status really)?

Comment: mbojko/noam, server-side code is in MVC controller and then class and I have break points there. So when large # of rows are copied, control does not hit those breakpoints, rather hits ' tap(data => { ' in validateReportData and then catchError(this.handleError) is called.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the data limit?